# URLs in emails end up having query parameters encrypted using (polyalphabetic?) cipher

Tags: email, url, encryption, privacy, query-string

My web application uses a 3rd party messaging platform to send emails to its users. These emails contain URLs that point to my web application and have query parameters. Some parameters are used to personalize what's displayed to the user and some to track marketing-related data (utm parameters).

I noticed that in case of some users, when they use the URL from email to access the web app, query parameters are scrambled using what looks like a polyalphabetic cipher. For example, I noticed that the word "customer" from one of the parameters is replaced with "dhfgbzfe" for a lot (maybe all) users.

My hypothesis is that affected users either have some privacy settings on their mailing server, or a browser extension that scrambles parameters.

Has anyone else encountered this? What could be the source of scrambling?